# How to add systemtray icons on dock

Tags: wingpanel, plank

Is there a way to make tray icons appear on the dock instead of adding PPAs and stuff?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly system tray icons programs, but can be useful depending on what you want to achieve exactly :

- you can put icons in Plank dock and associate them with a program or a script through defining `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`
- some 'docklets' are already available with `'Ctrl + right click the Dock' -> Preferences -> Docklets`

Good explanations and examples are provided here : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/plank